# Конструктор Android в Visual Studio

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, конструктор

Решил сделать программку на шарпе для андроид. Добавил в VS installer все инструменты для андроид розработки. Запустил проект - но кроме одной вкладки с кодом больше нечего нету. Есть ли у Android такая же вкладка как и у Winforms конструктор.

Comment: Я так понимаю, для разработки Вы выбрали Xamarin?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да